# Winforms: Controls not visible after added programmatically

Tags: winforms, controls, invisible

I want to create a simple FileExplorer Control for a video player.

Here is the code:

```
namespace CustomControls
{
    public interface IScrollable
    {
        float visiblePercent { get; set; }
        float ScrollSpeedMultiplier { get; set; }
        int scrollValue { get; set; }

        CustomScrollBar scrollBar { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace CustomControls {
    public partial class ScrollablePanel : UserControl, IScrollable {
        private int _scrollValue;
        private int _totalWheelDelta;

        private int totalWheelDelta {
            get => _totalWheelDelta;
            set {
                SetTotalDelta(value);
            }
        }

        public int Count => panelInner.Controls.Count;

        public bool VisibleControls => panelInner.Controls.OfType<Panel>().All(p => p.Visible);

        public float visiblePercent { get; set; }

        public int scrollValue {
            get { return _scrollValue; }
            set {
                _scrollValue = value;
                if (scrollBar != null && scrollBar.value != _scrollValue)
                    scrollBar.value = _scrollValue;
                SetTotalDeltaByScrollValue(value);
                ScrollThrough();
            }
        }

        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), Browsable(true), DefaultValue(0), Category("Behavior"), Description("Die dazugehörige Scrollbar")]
        public CustomScrollBar scrollBar { get; set; }

        public float ScrollSpeedMultiplier { get; set; }

        public ScrollablePanel() {
            InitializeComponent();
            panelInner.MouseWheel += panelInner_MouseWheel;
        }

        protected override ControlCollection CreateControlsInstance() {
            return new ScrollablePanelElementCollection(this, this.panelInner);
        }

        private void ScrollablePanel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            OnControlsChanged();
        }

        private void panelInner_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
            if (visiblePercent >= 1.0f)
                return;

            totalWheelDelta += (int)(e.Delta * ScrollSpeedMultiplier);

            scrollValue = (100 * SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollLines * totalWheelDelta) / ((Height - panelInner.Height) * SystemData.scrollDeltaModifier);

            if (scrollBar != null)
                scrollValue = scrollBar.value = (100 * SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollLines * totalWheelDelta) / ((Height - panelInner.Height) * SystemData.scrollDeltaModifier);
        }

        private void ScrollThrough() {
            panelInner.Location = new Point(0, (int)((Height - panelInner.Height) * (scrollValue / 100.0f)));
        }

        private void panelInner_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e) {
            OnControlsChanged();
        }

        private void panelInner_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e) {
            OnControlsChanged();
        }

        private void OnControlsChanged() {
            int height = int.MinValue;

            foreach (Control control in panelInner.Controls)
                if (control.Visible)
                    height = Math.Max(height, control.Bottom);

            panelInner.Height = height;

            ScrollablePanel_Resize(this, new EventArgs());

            if (panelInner.Height > 0)
                visiblePercent = (float)Height / panelInner.Height;
            else
                visiblePercent = 1.0f;

            if (scrollBar != null)
                scrollBar.largeChange = (int)(visiblePercent * 100);
        }

        private void ScrollablePanel_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            panelInner.Width = Width;
        }

        private void SetTotalDelta(int value) {
            int lines = SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollLines * (value / SystemData.scrollDeltaModifier);
            int deltaHeight = Height - panelInner.Height;

            if (lines > 0)
                _totalWheelDelta = 0;
            else if (lines < deltaHeight)
                _totalWheelDelta = (deltaHeight * SystemData.scrollDeltaModifier) / SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollLines;
            else
                _totalWheelDelta = value;
        }

        private void SetTotalDeltaByScrollValue(int value) {
            int deltaHeight = Height - panelInner.Height;

            totalWheelDelta = (deltaHeight * SystemData.scrollDeltaModifier * scrollValue) / (100 * SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollLines);
        }

        public void Clear() {
            panelInner.Controls.Clear();
        }
    }

    public class ScrollablePanelElementCollection : Control.ControlCollection {
        private Control container;

        public ScrollablePanelElementCollection(Control owner, Panel container) : base(owner) { this.container = container; }

        public override void Add(Control value) {
            if (this.Count == 0)
                base.Add(value);
            else
                container.Controls.Add(value);
        }
    }
}

namespace MagererPlayer {
    public partial class FileExplorer : UserControl, IScrollable {
        private string _directory;

        public float visiblePercent {
            get => scrollablePanel.visiblePercent;
            set => scrollablePanel.visiblePercent = value;
        }
        
        public int scrollValue {
            get => scrollablePanel.scrollValue;
            set => scrollablePanel.scrollValue = value;
        }
        
        public CustomScrollBar scrollBar {
            get => scrollablePanel.scrollBar;
            set => scrollablePanel.scrollBar = value;
        }

        public string Directory {
            get => this._directory;
            set {
                if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(value)) {
                    this._directory = value;
                    GetDirectory();
                }
            }
        }

        public float ScrollSpeedMultiplier { get; set; }

        public EventHandler OnDirectoryChanged = null;
        public EventHandler<FileSelectedEventArgs> OnFileSelected = null;

        public FileExplorer() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FileExplorer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            AdjustSize();
        }

        private void FileExplorer_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            AdjustSize();
        }

        private void AdjustSize() {

        }

        private void GetDirectory() {
            scrollablePanel.Clear();
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(this.Directory);

            int offset = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(this.Directory) != null ? 1 : 0;

            int colCount = scrollablePanel.Width / 145;
            string[] dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(new string(this.Directory.Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)).ToArray()));
            Array.Sort(dirs);

            if (offset == 1) {
                DirectoryInfo parent = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(this.Directory);
                scrollablePanel.Controls.Add(GetExplorerItem(parent.FullName, "..", new Point(0, 0)));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++)
                scrollablePanel.Controls.Add(GetExplorerItem(dirs[i], new DirectoryInfo(dirs[i]).Name, new Point(((i + offset) % colCount) * 145, (i + offset) / colCount * 115 + 10)));

            offset += dirs.Length;

            dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(new string(this.Directory.Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)).ToArray()), "*.mp4", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            Array.Sort(dirs);

            for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++)
                scrollablePanel.Controls.Add(GetExplorerItem(dirs[i], new FileInfo(dirs[i]).Name, new Point(((i + offset) % colCount) * 145, (i + offset) / colCount * 115 + 10)));

            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(scrollablePanel.Count);
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(scrollablePanel.VisibleControls);
            this.Invalidate();
        }

        private Panel GetExplorerItem(string path, string text, Point location) {
            BunifuImageButton bunifuImageButton = new BunifuImageButton();
            Label label = new Label();
            Panel panel = new Panel();

            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(path)) {
                bunifuImageButton.Image = Properties.Resources.folder;
                bunifuImageButton.Click += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e) {
                    this.Directory = path;
                };
            } else if (System.IO.File.Exists(path)) {
                bunifuImageButton.Image = Properties.Resources.video_1;
            }
            
            bunifuImageButton.ImageActive = null;
            bunifuImageButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 0);
            bunifuImageButton.Name = "bunifuImageButton";
            bunifuImageButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 70);
            bunifuImageButton.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            bunifuImageButton.TabStop = false;
            bunifuImageButton.Zoom = 5;
            bunifuImageButton.Cursor = Cursors.Hand; 

            label.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Century Gothic", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, 0);
            label.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(224, 224, 224);
            label.Name = "label";
            label.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
            label.Size = new Size(145, 40);
            label.Text = text;
            label.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            label.AutoEllipsis = true;

            panel.Controls.Add(bunifuImageButton);
            panel.Controls.Add(label);
            panel.Location = location;
            panel.Name = "panel";
            panel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(145, 110);

            return panel;
        }

        private void textBoxUrl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
                this.Directory = this.textBoxUrl.Text;
                this.textBoxUrl.Text = this.Directory;
            }
        }
    }

    public class FileSelectedEventArgs : EventArgs {
        public FileInfo File { get; }

        public FileSelectedEventArgs(string path) {
            File = new FileInfo(path);
        }

        public FileSelectedEventArgs(FileInfo info) {
            File = info;
        }
    }
}
```

The Scrollable panel contains an inner panel that gets moved up and down. The FileExplorer contains a textbox for the URL, a button, and a scrollable panel.

My problem is that when I run the application everything works fine. When I go to the parent folder (IMPORTANT, NOT A SUBDIR) and reenter the folder all controls that should be there are invisible, but they were added to the inner panel's control collection.

This is the only folder dir where this error occurs: D:\Serien\Anime\Yu-Gi-Oh! Zexal

**Output of System.Diagnostics from FileExplorer.GetDirectory:**

```
D:\Serien\Anime\Yu-Gi-Oh! Zexal
3
True
D:\Serien\Anime
47
True
D:\Serien\Anime\Yu-Gi-Oh! Zexal
3
True
```

Screenshot of app start:
[image]

Screenshot after reenter:
[image]

Comment: The first thing you have to do is remove this: `scrollablePanel.Clear();` and replace it with method that disposes of the Controls added to the Container (loop backwars the collection and dispose of all Controls added before). Since you also add event handlers, you have to unsubscribe those, too. Don't use an in-lined delegate, use a method as the event handler. No idea why you're doing this: `.GetFiles(new string(this.Directory.Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)).ToArray())` and why you're constantly setting a TextBox.Text property with a value you just extracted from it.

Comment: For the rest, you need to debug your code and see what each variable/property you set actually contains.

Comment: 1. I did `new string(this.Directory.Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)).ToArray()` only because I wanted to make sure that no control chars are inside the string for example \r\n after pressing enter inside the textbox.

Comment: 2. I set the text of the textbox so that if the setter of Directory does not set the variable because the Directory does not exist the textview gets reset to the previous dir

Comment: 3. I already debugged and every value is correct. The controls are just not visible. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: 1. The first thing you do when `e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter` is to suppress the keypress (`e.SuppressKeyPress = true;`). A  non-multiline TextBox doesn't register line feeds 2. this: `this.Directory = this.textBoxUrl.Text; this.textBoxUrl.Text = this.Directory;` is useless, but not your problem. 3. That's actually a problem. See the *dispose of the Controls you added* part of the previous comment (`[ContainerControl].Clear();` doesn't dispose of anything).

Comment: 1. You don't get what `this.Directory = this.textBoxUrl.Text; this.textBoxUrl.Text = this.Directory;` does. Have a look at the setter of `FileExplorer.Directory`. 2. Disposing does not solve my problem.

Comment: 1. `FileExplorer.Directory` sets a backing field with the value that comes from `textBoxUrl.Text`, then calls `GetDirectory()` which, in turn, tries to set the `textBoxUrl.Text` to the value it got from it. This all can be avoided if, in the internal code, you use the backing field and not the property to access a value. 2. Because you didn't actually do it.

Comment: I tried disposing right after you mentioned it but of cause it does not work. Why should disposing the previous elements have an effect on the drawing process of the new ones. They are there they are in the collection, They have the right values, they are just not visible.

Comment: I cannot see the code (you haven't update your question), but that's the important part. You're also assigning images from the Resources directly, those objects need to be disposed, too. Or, better, assigned to filed values and used for each Control that needs them, the disposed of when the main Control is disposed. The `ExplorerItem` is build on the fly, but it should be as UserControl, to manage all of it's internal, unmanaged, objects. Then, you're using all hard-coded values for the positions that you alone can debug. Check whether your Controls are outside the visible area.

Comment: BTW, you could replace the view containing all the `ExplorerItems` objects with a ListView in Tile or LargeIcon mode, or, if you want to use single objects, a FlowLayoutPanel. In either case, you don't have to worry anymore about the Items placement, it's all automatic. Disposing of the unmanaged objects is still mandatory and, if you use single objects that are not UserControls, also unsubscribing to events.